# Pandas or numpy loop to find the 12 hour rolling minimum of each column and output it as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I use pandas or numpy to do this? I need to calculate a rolling window (minimum) of station data, and either add it as a new column or output it to a new dataframe all together.

I currently have the following code:

dataframe data:

```
stamp   year    month   day time    10805   2855    3172    10888   7485    3088    2896    7550    46367   2925    51739   3231    2942    10795   10724   10667   10727   2967    27476   3244    44344   3318    28011   3193    10784   3328    50091   3259    3157    10821   10785   10660   49808   44203   3062    31408   32149   10915   31407   2180    26971   32254   2224    32230   27212   32256   10708   10225   32257   32395   32313   2263    2265    1920    31411   2273    8804    32433   10725   2312    10907   10889   10882   3721    50821   3471    27741   26857   26866   29886   8993    7333    3605    3853    10185   29593   10881   3649    10884   27119   10927   10188   3562    3698
1/1/1994 0:00   1994    1   1   0:00        -20.5                   -15.3                   -16.4                       -14.9       -21.3                       -22.8                                   -24.4                                                                   -5.5        -19.7       -8.4                                -38.6       -28.7                                                                       -30.3
1/1/1994 1:00   1994    1   1   1:00        -20.3                   -15.2                   -16.2                       -14.8       -21.5                       -22.4                                   -23.6                                                                   -5.3        -19.8       -9.3                                -38.4       -26.7                                                                       -31.1
1/1/1994 2:00   1994    1   1   2:00        -20.6                   -15.2                   -17.4                       -14.1       -22                     -22.8                                   -23.2                                                                   -4.8        -20     -8.8                                -38.7       -26                                                                     -31.3
1/1/1994 3:00   1994    1   1   3:00        -19.7                   -15                 -18.3                       -14.3       -22.1                       -22.6                                   -22.9                                                                   -4.9        -20.3       -9.4                                -38.9       -25.6                                                                       -32.4
1/1/1994 4:00   1994    1   1   4:00        -19.2                   -15.4                   -18.2                       -14.5       -22.5                       -22.5                                   -23.3                                                                   -4.8        -20.3       -8.4                                -38.4       -26                                                                     -31.1
1/1/1994 5:00   1994    1   1   5:00        -18.8                   -16.3                   -18.4                       -14.4       -22.5                       -22.5                                   -23.3                                                                   -5.1        -20.9       -8.1                                -30.5       -26                                                                     -30.7
1/1/1994 6:00   1994    1   1   6:00        -18.6                   -17                 -18.9                       -14.3       -23.2                       -22.8                                   -23.2                                                                   -3      -25.8       -9.3                                -30.8       -25.6                                                                       -30.3
1/1/1994 7:00   1994    1   1   7:00        -18.6                   -16.6                   -19.4                       -14     -23.6                       -22.9                                   -23.3                                                                   -7.2        -25     -10.2                               -30.4       -25.1                                                                       -30.1
1/1/1994 8:00   1994    1   1   8:00        -18.7                   -16                 -19.5                       -14     -24.1                       -23.1                                   -23.3                                                                   -7.8        -24.6       -10.9                               -30.3       -24.5                                                                       -29.3
1/1/1994 9:00   1994    1   1   9:00        -18.9                   -16.4                   -19.9                       -14.3       -24.1                       -23.1                                   -24                                                                 -8.2        -24.5       -10.7                               -31.4       -24.4                                                                       -29
1/1/1994 10:00  1994    1   1   10:00       -18.9                   -16.5                   -19.6                       -14.5       -24.2                       -23.7                                   -24.7                                                                   -8.2        -24.1       -10.5                               -31     -24.1                                                                       -27.9
1/1/1994 11:00  1994    1   1   11:00       -18.7                   -16.3                   -19.6                       -15.2       -24.3                       -23.7                                   -24.9                                                                   -8.3        -23.9       -10.8                               -31     -23.8                                                                       -27
```

The data exists in a .csv file (this is just another view of the same dataset above).

```
stamp,year,month,day,time,10805,2855,3172,10888,7485,3088,2896,7550,46367,2925,51739,3231,2942,10795,10724,10667,10727,2967,27476,3244,44344,3318,28011,3193,10784,3328,50091,3259,3157,10821,10785,10660,49808,44203,3062,31408,32149,10915,31407,2180,26971,32254,2224,32230,27212,32256,10708,10225,32257,32395,32313,2263,2265,1920,31411,2273,8804,32433,10725,2312,10907,10889,10882,3721,50821,3471,27741,26857,26866,29886,8993,7333,3605,3853,10185,29593,10881,3649,10884,27119,10927,10188,3562,3698
"1994-01-01 00:00","1994","01","01","00:00",,"-20.5",,,,,"-15.3",,,,,"-16.4",,,,,,"-14.9",,"-21.3",,,,,,"-22.8",,,,,,,,,"-24.4",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-5.5",,"-19.7",,"-8.4",,,,,,,,"-38.6",,"-28.7",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-30.3"
"1994-01-01 01:00","1994","01","01","01:00",,"-20.3",,,,,"-15.2",,,,,"-16.2",,,,,,"-14.8",,"-21.5",,,,,,"-22.4",,,,,,,,,"-23.6",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-5.3",,"-19.8",,"-9.3",,,,,,,,"-38.4",,"-26.7",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-31.1"
"1994-01-01 02:00","1994","01","01","02:00",,"-20.6",,,,,"-15.2",,,,,"-17.4",,,,,,"-14.1",,"-22.0",,,,,,"-22.8",,,,,,,,,"-23.2",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-4.8",,"-20.0",,"-8.8",,,,,,,,"-38.7",,"-26.0",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-31.3"
"1994-01-01 03:00","1994","01","01","03:00",,"-19.7",,,,,"-15.0",,,,,"-18.3",,,,,,"-14.3",,"-22.1",,,,,,"-22.6",,,,,,,,,"-22.9",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-4.9",,"-20.3",,"-9.4",,,,,,,,"-38.9",,"-25.6",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-32.4"
"1994-01-01 04:00","1994","01","01","04:00",,"-19.2",,,,,"-15.4",,,,,"-18.2",,,,,,"-14.5",,"-22.5",,,,,,"-22.5",,,,,,,,,"-23.3",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-4.8",,"-20.3",,"-8.4",,,,,,,,"-38.4",,"-26.0",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-31.1"
"1994-01-01 05:00","1994","01","01","05:00",,"-18.8",,,,,"-16.3",,,,,"-18.4",,,,,,"-14.4",,"-22.5",,,,,,"-22.5",,,,,,,,,"-23.3",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-5.1",,"-20.9",,"-8.1",,,,,,,,"-30.5",,"-26.0",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-30.7"
"1994-01-01 06:00","1994","01","01","06:00",,"-18.6",,,,,"-17.0",,,,,"-18.9",,,,,,"-14.3",,"-23.2",,,,,,"-22.8",,,,,,,,,"-23.2",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-3.0",,"-25.8",,"-9.3",,,,,,,,"-30.8",,"-25.6",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-30.3"
"1994-01-01 07:00","1994","01","01","07:00",,"-18.6",,,,,"-16.6",,,,,"-19.4",,,,,,"-14.0",,"-23.6",,,,,,"-22.9",,,,,,,,,"-23.3",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-7.2",,"-25.0",,"-10.2",,,,,,,,"-30.4",,"-25.1",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-30.1"
"1994-01-01 08:00","1994","01","01","08:00",,"-18.7",,,,,"-16.0",,,,,"-19.5",,,,,,"-14.0",,"-24.1",,,,,,"-23.1",,,,,,,,,"-23.3",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-7.8",,"-24.6",,"-10.9",,,,,,,,"-30.3",,"-24.5",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-29.3"
"1994-01-01 09:00","1994","01","01","09:00",,"-18.9",,,,,"-16.4",,,,,"-19.9",,,,,,"-14.3",,"-24.1",,,,,,"-23.1",,,,,,,,,"-24.0",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-8.2",,"-24.5",,"-10.7",,,,,,,,"-31.4",,"-24.4",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-29.0"
"1994-01-01 10:00","1994","01","01","10:00",,"-18.9",,,,,"-16.5",,,,,"-19.6",,,,,,"-14.5",,"-24.2",,,,,,"-23.7",,,,,,,,,"-24.7",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-8.2",,"-24.1",,"-10.5",,,,,,,,"-31.0",,"-24.1",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-27.9"
"1994-01-01 11:00","1994","01","01","11:00",,"-18.7",,,,,"-16.3",,,,,"-19.6",,,,,,"-15.2",,"-24.3",,,,,,"-23.7",,,,,,,,,"-24.9",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-8.3",,"-23.9",,"-10.8",,,,,,,,"-31.0",,"-23.8",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-27.0"
"1994-01-01 12:00","1994","01","01","12:00",,"-18.6",,,,,"-16.1",,,,,"-19.8",,,,,,"-15.1",,"-24.7",,,,,,"-23.6",,,,,,,,,"-24.8",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-8.5",,"-23.6",,"-10.9",,,,,,,,"-31.4",,"-23.2",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-26.6"
"1994-01-01 13:00","1994","01","01","13:00",,"-18.6",,,,,"-15.9",,,,,"-19.7",,,,,,"-15.4",,"-24.3",,,,,,"-23.9",,,,,,,,,"-24.5",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-9.3",,"-23.3",,"-11.4",,,,,,,,"-31.9",,"-22.8",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-25.9"
"1994-01-01 14:00","1994","01","01","14:00",,"-19.4",,,,,"-15.9",,,,,"-19.6",,,,,,"-15.2",,"-24.4",,,,,,"-24.7",,,,,,,,,"-24.7",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-10.2",,"-23.4",,"-11.9",,,,,,,,"-33.2",,"-22.6",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"-24.9"
```

loads the dataframe

```
df=pd.read_csv('dataframedata.csv')

df.head()
```

Filtering the dataset to only have the days of interest for within each year.

```
df=df[(df.day >= 9) & (df.day <= 20)]
```

create a list of all the stations in the dataframe while dropping all the other information.

```
st=list(df)
st=st[5:]
st=pd.DataFrame(st)
```

How would I go about creating a loop that would use the values from st to select columns to execute the following function (which calculates the running 12 hr minimum for each cell while moving through the column)?

```
st['newcolumnname'] = df.rolling(12).min()[st]
```

Ultimately I am trying to calculate the 12 hour rolling minimum for each value at each station (column). With particular interest on the days 9 to 20th of each month.

Comment: please provide a working example, not only data which can't be used with your code!

Comment: Maybe also consider bringing this data into better format via `df.set_index(['stamp', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'time'], inplace=True`
and `df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_5':'station',0:'value'})`.

Especially the `set_index` will help you alot!

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: No Problem, that's why I said that! :-)

Comment: I am just getting used to python. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first mistake is creating a DataFrame out of those columns. You can just index `df.columns`.

```
st = df.columns[5:].tolist()
```

Next, convert `stamp` to `datetime` -

```
df['stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['stamp'])
```

Finally, call `Rolling.min` -

```
df[st].rolling(12).min()
```

From your data, it seems recordings are made at neat 1 hour intervals. If this isn't the case, slap on a `set_index` + `resample` call first and then find the rolling minimum.

```
df.set_index('stamp').[st]resample('1H').first().rolling(12).min()
```

Note that in either case, the result is a *dataframe*, you *cannot* put this inside a column.

Comment: Thank you COLDSPEED ! I'll give this a try.